# Why is the statement "f == (float)(double)f;" wrong?

Tags: c

I have recently taken a lecture of System Programming, and my professor told me that `f == (float)(double) f` is which wrong that I cannot get.

I know that `double` type loses its data when converted to `float`, but I believe the loss happens only if the stored number in `double` type cannot be expressed in `float` type.

Shouldn't it be true as same as `x == (int)(double)x;` is true?

the picture is the way I'm understanding it

[image]

---

I'm so sorry that I didn't make my question clearly.

the question is not about declaration, but about double type conversion.
I hope you don't lose your precious time because of my fault.

Comment: What reasoning did your professor give for why this is wrong?

Comment: The only thing I see wrong is that you initialize the variable with itself.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that statement ?

Comment: @Eugenesh I did edit the question. Sorry.

Comment: @DanielPryden He didn't mentioned any reason, just saying it is wrong.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Nothing, it is just one of simple quiz about conversion my professor showed to the students.

Comment: AFAIK float to double is a lossless conversion

Comment: What type is `f`?

Comment: @VeomchanKim "He didn't mentioned any reason, just saying it is wrong" --> What was the explanation when you asked for the reason?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming [IEC 60559](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), the result of `f == (float)(double) f` depends on the type of `f`.

Further assuming `f` is a `float`, then there's nothing "wrong" about the expression - it will evaluate to `true` (unless `f` held [`NaN`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan), in which case the expression will evaluate to `false`).

On the other hand, `x == (int)(double)x` (assuming `x` is a `int`) is (potentially) problematic, since a double precision IEC 60559 floating point value only has 53 bits for the significand<sup>1</sup>, which cannot represent all possible values of an `int` if it uses more than 53 bits for its value on your platform (admittedly rare). So it will evaluate to `true` on platforms where `int`s are 32-bit (using 31 bits for the value), and might evaluate to `false` on platforms where `int`s are 64-bit (using 63 bits for the value) (depending on the value).

Relevant quotes from the C standard (6.3.1.4 and 6.3.1.5) :

> When a value of integer type is converted to a real floating type, if the value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged.

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

> When a value of real floating type is converted to a real floating type, if the value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged.

---

<sup>1</sup> a double precision IEC 60559 floating point value consists of 1 bit for the sign, 11 bits for the exponent, and 53 bits for the significand (of which 1 is implied and not stored) - totaling 64 (stored) bits.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I found my mistake again and edit the question again.
I'm so sorry

and he said double type can express every numbers that int type expresses, you mean he taught me wrong?

Comment: @VeomchanKim : edited my answer accordingly - the gist is the same.

Comment: @VeomchanKim : the C standard allows the `int` type to have a larger range than can be represented exactly by the `double` type. On most of today's platforms, that's not a concern though. So, strictly speaking, that statement by your professor ("double type can express every numbers that int type expresses") is wrong, but practically speaking (or when speaking about a specific environment), the statement is fine.

Comment: Thank you again for your comments, I appreciate them very much.

Comment: Detail:  Typical double can exactly represent all  `int54_t` (which has sign and 53 bit of precision and `double` has sign and 52 explicitly encoded + 1 implied precision bits).

Comment: @chux : I'm unsure if your comment is intended to correct my answer, or to expand on it. In the former case, is it because I didn't mention that one of the significand bits in a `double` is implied ? Or is it because I didn't mention the sign bit ? If so, I left those details out for simplicity.

Comment: @chux : added the extra detail in anyway as a footnote.

Comment: Answer was comparing the 53 precision capability of `double` against the _size_ of a 64-bit integer and not its 63 precision.  Your good addition helps clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the question as posed in the title literally,

> Why is the statement “f == (float)(double)f;” wrong?

the statement is "wrong" not in any way related to the representation of floating point values but because it is trivially optimized away by any compiler and thus you might as well have saved the electrons used to store it. It is exactly equivalent to the statement

```
1;
```

or, if you like, to the statement (from the original question)

```
x == (int)(double)x;
```

(which has exactly the same effect as that in the title, regardless of the available precision of the types `int`, `float`, and `double`, i.e. none whatsoever).

Programming being somewhat concerned with precision you should perhaps take note of the difference between a *statement* and an *expression*. An *expression* has a value which might be true or false or something else, but when you add a semicolon (as you did in the question) it becomes a *statement* (as you called it in the question) and in the absence of side effects the compiler is free to throw it away.

Comment: what about NaNs?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen a NaN will never compare equal to itself or anything else, but without side effects the statement `0;` is still the same as the statement `1;`.

Answer (score 0):

`NaN`s are retained through float => double => float, but they not equal themselves.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float f = HUGE_VALF;
    printf("%d\n", f == (float)(double) f);
    f = NAN;
    printf("%d\n", f == (float)(double) f);
    printf("%d\n", f == f);
}
```

Prints

```
1
0 
0
```